# Alternative to prepared SQL "USE" statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a SQL script to automate the creation of a new database and its tables. The current script is as follows...

```
-- Create a database with the defined name
SET @query = CONCAT("CREATE DATABASE ", @database);
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

-- Create a user with all privileges to the new database
SET @query = CONCAT("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ", @database, ".* TO '", @username, "'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '", @password, "'");
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

-- Use the new database
SET @query = CONCAT("USE ", @database);
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The final statement would allow the rest of my script to be "normal" SQL rather than prepared, because I could use `table` instead of `database.table`.

Unfortunately, the script reports

> ERROR 1295 (HY000) at line 34: This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet

Is there another way to accomplish the effect of `USE`? I know I could use a SQL dump of a prepared database, but it has two disadvantages:

1. It adds another file to my project
2. It would make it harder to alter the database structure during development

Comment: you can always use queries like these `SELECT [columns] FROM [database].[table]` also the same way for update or delete queries without the use of the query `USE database`...

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think his problem is that the database name is determined dynamically in the `@database` variable, so he can't hard-code it into the queries. That solution means he'll have to use dynamic SQL for everything. Unfortunately, I can't think of any other solution.

Comment: The question is tagged `php`. Can't you generate queries that use `$database.tablename` in PHP?

Comment: @Barmar using PHP as a setup script might be my best option. I just hate the extra lines involved in using PDO or mysqli.

Comment: I'm not talking about the setup script, I'm talking about the code that performs the queries. When you open a DB connection with mysqli or PDO, you specify the default database as a parameter.

Comment: @Barmar Right, but that would still require two files... So, one setup.sql script to create the database and another setup.php file to use that database and create the default table schema.